# Compilation issue with Assert.aasertthat in org.junit package

Tags: junit, assert

In our Application unit testcode, Assert.asserThat() method throws a compiler issue stating

> assertThat(someintValue,is(100));
>
> method assertThat(Integer, Matcher) in the type Assert is not
>   applicable for the arguments (int,   Matcher)

I am using jdk1.8 and this issue happens in my STS IDE with junit-4.8.2jar. Whereas when I use Eclipse IDE with the same jar/jdk 1.8, this compilation issue is not present. 
I checked ordering of jars in the order/export tab and the settings are similar to what I have in Eclipse IDE. Not sure why this compilation issue happens in STS 3.7.0.
Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: I see this issue often when I misuse the matchers, can you show us your code so we can help you better?

Comment: assertThat(someintValue,is(100));

Comment: Please add this to your question instead of a comment